# Alternative approaches to comparing values

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying this question from CodingBat

> Given three ints, a b c, return True if one of b or c is "close" (differing by
>    at most 1), while the other is "far", differing from both other values by 2 or 
>    more. Note: abs(num) computes the absolute value of a number.

```
close_far(1, 2, 10) → True
close_far(1, 2, 3) → False
close_far(4, 1, 3) → True
```

I know i can solve this by a series of if else statement but it would really long , are there any other approaches to this question???

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: The Note: in the problem description is a very good clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem can be greatly simplified, without loss of generality, by sorting:

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
  x, y, z = sorted([a, b, c])
  delta_close, delta_far = sorted([y - x, z - y])
  return delta_close <= 1 and delta_far >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
    def close(x, y): return abs(x - y) <= 1
    def far(x, y): return abs(x - y) >= 2
    return (close(b, a) and far(c, a) and far(c, b) or
            close(c, a) and far(b, a) and far(b, c))

>>> close_far(1, 2, 10)
True
>>> close_far(1, 2, 3)
False
>>> close_far(4, 1, 3)
True
```

Comment: Probably better to use explicit parens to group `snd` and `or` operators, though of course it's right as written.

Comment: @user2284926 I urge you to take a look at the approach by wim which is much more adaptable

Answer (score 0):

Little help:

`def close_far(a, b, c):
  return ((abs(a-c) >= 2 and  abs(a-b) <= 1) and (abs(b-c) >= 2)) or ((abs(a-c) <= 1 and abs(a-b) >= 2) and (abs(b-c) >= 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
    return not ((is_close(a,b)==is_close(a,c)) or is_close(b,c))


def is_close(num1, num2):
    return abs(num1-num2)<=1
```